# is it possible to select from a combination of IDs from one column n display each IDs name?

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

Well its kind of complicated to describe what i am trying to do, let me explain completely. first of all i have selected one or more than one option from multiple selection and implode it into a column, now i want display each selections IDs name in one column.

1st implode:

```
$gallery_category = implode('  ',$_POST['gallery_category']);
```

then trying to display each unique ids name, like this

```
$gallery_category = $row['gallery_category'];
$output = explode(" ", $gallery_category);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM  gallery_category WHERE gallery_category_name2 = "'.$output.'"';
$select_categories_name = mysqli_query($connection,$query);  

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_name)) {
    $gallery_category_name = $row['gallery_category_name'];
    echo "<td> $gallery_category_name</td>";
}
```

getting error like: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: The $output variable is an array so you need to use $output[0]. This will only return one category which is not what you want. When you do the implode action use the "," as the separator. In the query you can use WHERE find_in_set('{$gallery_category}',gallery_category_name2) -- or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$gallery_category = $row['gallery_category'];
$output = explode(" ", $gallery_category);//this is an array so have to give it in a loop or specify by index 
foreach($output as $category)
{   
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM  gallery_category WHERE gallery_category_name2 = "'.$category.'"';
    $select_categories_name = mysqli_query($connection,$query);         
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_name)) {
            $gallery_category_name = $row['gallery_category_name'];
            echo "$gallery_category_name";    
        }
}
```

This should work, if not pls comment.

Comment: works fine, thanks a lot, just a lil correction  please edit the <td> out of foreach. :)